# OpenGL 3.0 glVertexAttribPointer: legacy works, forward compatible (core) doesn’t

Tags: c, sdl-2, glew, opengl-3

This code works fine in the legacy OpenGL 3.0, but fails in the forward compatible mode (4.1 and 3.3 on my setup). I’ve tested it on the hardware and the sofware implementations. I use SDL to get the OpenGL context, and GLEW to find some functions. Adding the line below to my code make the problem.

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);
```

The problematic part of code is call to glVertexAttribPointer

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glb.vbo);
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    size * sizeof(GLfloat),
    input,
    GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW
);
test_gl_errors(); /* GL_NO_ERROR */

glUseProgram(glb.program);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(glb.vert_array);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(glb.colour_array); /* I use this later. */

test_gl_errors(); /* GL_NO_ERROR */
glVertexAttribPointer(
    glb.vert_array,
    2,
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    5 * sizeof(GLfloat),
    0
);
test_gl_errors(); /* GL_INVALID_OPERATION */
```

I would like to add more code, but there is a lot of stuff. Reading information from the link below didn’t help me. Any suggestions?
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml

My OpenGL setup:

- Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAPE VERDE (DRM 2.45.0 / 4.7.2-1-ck, LLVM 3.8.1)
- Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)
- Mesa3D: 12.0.1

Comment: Do you have a VAO bound when you make the call? They are required in the core profile.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I’ve added some more code.

Comment: I still don't see a VAO. There have to be `glGenVertexArray()` and `glBindVertexArray()` calls somewhere before this.

Comment: Tank You. I’ve added these two functions and it works.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Would You like to post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working code, based on comments from Reto Koradi.

```
glBindVertexArray(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glb.vao); /* <-- NEW !!! */
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glb.vbo);
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    size * sizeof(GLfloat),
    input,
    GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW
);

glUseProgram(glb.program);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(glb.vert_array);

glVertexAttribPointer(
    glb.vert_array,
    2,
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    5 * sizeof(GLfloat),
    0
);
test_gl_errors(); /* GL_NO_ERROR */
```